# Using a local Docker container to call out to AWS batch and sumbit jobs and post data after jobs are complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I have a local dev environment running Docker containers. I have since migrated to using AWS batch to run these jobs and post results in my 'prod' environment. I would like to mirror this functionality locally. Essentially set up an endpoint that my local environment can post these jobs and wait for response. I know this is is rather vague, however I am just looking for core concepts to investigate in order to achieve this.

Comment: I think you might want to look into using AWS SAM, which is like an extension of CloudFormation. It allows you to write your AWS infrastructure as code and deploy it either locally (in a docker) or as an AWS stack. https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/

Comment: Thank you for your input, SAM looks promising!